# FFmpeg command to cut video into smaller segments not working programmatically

Tags: java, ffmpeg

How to cut a video into smaller segment using ffmpeg in a Java program? The command works fine from terminal but doesn't when I try the same in my program.

Here's the code snippet

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p = runtime.exec("ffmpeg -i /Users/test/Desktop/demo.mp4 -ss 0 -t 2 -c:v copy copy.mp4");
}
```

Comment: Include the exact errors you are getting when you try this. If it's 'error 2', put the full path to ffmpeg in there.

Comment: Exit code is 127. Contents of stderr: ffmpeg -i /Users/test/Desktop/demo.mp4 -ss 0 -t 2 -c:v copy copy.mp4: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Runtime.exec()` is fraught with difficulties. A particular problem with `ffmpeg` is that it's likely to produce output -- to `stdout` or `stderr` or both -- and take some time to complete. The output needs to be collected up and processed, even it it's only copied to the terminal. Not only will the process block if it produces output and nothing consumes it, you really need to collect `stderr` to see any errors.

Bear in mind that `Runtime.exec()` is not a shell, and it won't necessarily parse command lines the way a shell would. It won't even necessarily look in the same places for executables as a shell will.

Another problem you're likely to have is that your Java program might complete before the process spawned by `exec()` does. You probably need a `Process.waitFor()` after the `exec()` if you want to wait.

I have some example code using `Runtime.exec()` with `stdout`/`stderr` processing on GitHub. However, the perils in using `Runtime.exec()` are discussed in many posts here.

[1] https://github.com/kevinboone/runtimeexec